# Plot different regression functions for different variables with Seaborn PairGrid, regplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My problem is, how do I plot a regression in seaborn PairGrid which would depend on which variable is plotted and not if it is upper/lower/diagonal position?
For example, I have the `tips` data set and I believe that the `'size'` is correlated as a second-order polynomial regardless of the other variable, ie. the entire row/column in the pairgrid I want to have like that, but nothing else. However, what I only can do is to map this correlation to the upper/lower triangle to **all plots**, like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

smoke = sns.PairGrid(tips, vars=['total_bill', 'tip','size'])
smoke.map_upper(sns.regplot, color = 'k', order=2)
smoke.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
smoke.map_lower(sns.regplot, color = 'b')
```

[image: Fig 1]

Is it possible with seaborn?
And if I go even further, what if I want to check/plot an exponential correlation between eg. `'tip'` and `'total_bill'` just within the pairgrid, is that possible? How would I do that?

I know I can just take this specific case outside and plot it separately or use [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) but I wonder if there is an easier way.
Thanks

---

EDIT (26.4.):
The additional question is how to use `hue` in this setup. If I use simply:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
vars = ['total_bill', 'tip','size']

smoke = sns.PairGrid(tips, vars=vars, hue='smoker')
smoke.map_upper(plt.scatter)
smoke.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
smoke.map_lower(plt.scatter)

# Add 2nd order polynomial regression to the 'size' column
for ax,y in zip(smoke.axes[:2,2],vars):
    sns.regplot(ax=ax, data=tips, x='size', y=y, order=2, scatter=False)
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xlabel('')

# Add logarithmic regression
sns.regplot(ax=smoke.axes[2,0], data=tips, x="total_bill", y='size', logx=True, scatter=False)
```

It does what I want, ie fit logarithmic regression, but very strangely. It puts the blue for the first row only, the orange for a second row only and then it creates green for first col, last row as shown in the following picture. So my question is how to fix it and why it occurs in the first place. Is it that `hue` creates new set of `axes` that are then needed to be iterated over?

[image: Fig 2. -- add hue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PairGrid` only lets you map the diagonal, the off-diagonal, and the upper and lower triangles. If you want more fine grain control over the plots, you can access the individual axes object using `PairGrid.axes` (2D array):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
vars = ['total_bill', 'tip','size']

smoke = sns.PairGrid(tips, vars=vars)
smoke.map_upper(plt.scatter, color = 'k')
smoke.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
smoke.map_lower(plt.scatter, color = 'b')

# Add 2nd order polynomial regression to the 'size' column
for ax,y in zip(smoke.axes[:2,2],vars):
    sns.regplot(ax=ax, data=tips, x='size', y=y, order=2, color='k', scatter=False)

# Add logarithmic regression
sns.regplot(ax=smoke.axes[2,0], data=tips, x="total_bill", y='size', logx=True, color='b', scatter=False)
```

[image]

**EDIT:** solution that works with hue-splitting

In this case, you have to do the regression on each subset of the data and plot on the same axes.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
vars = ['total_bill', 'tip','size']
hue_col = 'smoker'
hue_order=['Yes','No']

smoke = sns.PairGrid(tips, vars=vars, hue='smoker', hue_order=hue_order)
smoke.map_upper(plt.scatter)
smoke.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
smoke.map_lower(plt.scatter)

# Add 2nd order polynomial regression to the 'size' column
for ax,y in zip(smoke.axes[:2,2],vars):
    for hue in hue_order:
        sns.regplot(ax=ax, data=tips.loc[tips[hue_col]==hue], x='size', y=y, order=2, scatter=False)
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xlabel('')

# Add logarithmic regression
for hue in hue_order:
    sns.regplot(ax=smoke.axes[2,0], data=tips.loc[tips[hue_col]==hue], x="total_bill", y='size', logx=True, scatter=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to ask one thing, how would I add ```hue``` to it? If I do just ```smoke = sns.PairGrid(tips, vars=['total_bill', 'tip','size'], hue='smoker')```, it does it to only one of the plots (to the first hue group) and furthermore, the colour does not work always well -- it looks like it sometimes add new (that is the case when I remove ```color```, when I left it not specified). Is ```hue``` adding new axis therefore it's not working?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please update your question with the code you are using and an image demonstrating the issue

Comment: Now it's understandable and clear what problem I have in mind?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior of the regressions with different colors, but that does not really matter. `hue` does not create additional axes, it just splits the data. However, the regression lines that you added to the top-right and bottom left axes are not aware of any of that, those regressions are performed on the whole dataset. Do you want to regression lines, for smoker/no-smoker?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking it's doing. If I use ```hue```, it splits the scatter/kde/reg-plot into two different (you can see how if you just use ```sns.regplot``` in for example the ```map_lower``` part), so I thought it would work the same for the regression lines. but it doesn't. I cannot add the ```hue``` within the ```sns.regplot``` with the correlations/regression since it's not a ```regplot``` argument.

Comment: @MyWork I've added some code to show how I would deal with the hue levels

Comment: Thanks @Diziet Asahi, I'm still getting different colours of the ```[2,0]``` and ```[1,2]``` (ie not blue+orange but red and green and then some violet) but I haven't found the cause and seems not that relevant. So I'll accept your answer and thanks again for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, because you can specify the x- and y-variables separately, e.g.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

smoke = sns.PairGrid(tips, x_vars=['total_bill', 'tip','size'], y_vars=['size'])
smoke.map(sns.regplot, color = 'k', order=2)
smoke.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
```

[image: pairplot example]

To plot various kinds of regression functions, you would have to access each axes (subplot) individually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just this gives me:
```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```
in the last line:
```----> 9 smoke.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)```